# Changing location of the .AndroidStudioBeta folder

Tags: path, android-studio, directory

How do I change the location of the **.AndroidStudioBeta** folder, located at **\..\User\.AndroidStudioBeta** in Windows by default, without breaking anything?

/EDIT:

Found the answer.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963

> Locations can be changed by editing the following file:
>
> android-studio\bin\idea.properties

Answer (score 1):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963

> Locations can be changed by editing the following file:
>
> IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties